# How do I use the bluetooth module in conjunction with the multiprocessing module?

Tags: macos, concurrency, bluetooth, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing

I am using python 3.5 and OSX 10.13.2.

I am attempting to gather EEG data from a bluetooth EEG recording device while a human is watching a pygame GUI. Because the bluetooth device sends data at about 512 Hz and the pygame GUI updates at about 25Hz, I'm thinking that including the gathering of the bluetooth data and the updating of the GUI in the same loop/process is not appropriate.

Therefore, I want to create two concurrent processes: one for the gathering of bluetooth input and one for displaying/updating the pygame GUI. I think I have figured out how to run a pygame window in a separate process, but creating a separate process using the `multiprocessing` module that connects to and reads input from my bluetooth device is not working out well.

When I run the code below, execution seems to stop on this line `socket.connect(('B0:B4:48:F6:38:A1', 1))`: nothing in the `connect()` method is printed. Is this a problem with Mac OSX, the bluetooth module, Python, or something else? Does anyone know how I can fix this? If not, does anyone have a different way I could approach my initial problem of gathering data from a bluetooth device and updating a GUI in parallel using python 3.5?

```
import multiprocessing, time, bluetooth

def connect():
    socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
    try:
        socket.connect(('B0:B4:48:F6:38:A1', 1))
        print("connected to device!!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed to connect :(")


def wait_and_do_nothing():
    print("just sleeping over here in this process")
    time.sleep(5)

process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=connect, args=())
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=wait_and_do_nothing, args=())

process1.start()
process2.start()

process1.join()
process2.join()

print("finished")
```

The output of the above code is:
`finished`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. For one, I should have wrapped the multiprocessing code in an if statement like the one below. Two, I should have set the start method to 'spawn' instead of 'fork' like I do below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)

    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=connect, args=())
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=wait_and_do_nothing, args=())

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()
```